# Smaller legend keys Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, format, legend

I am trying to format my graph nicely, but I can't figure out how to scale down the legend picture of my line.

Is there a simple way to make that GDP legend line smaller?
Thank you.

[See picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bqKF.png)

[Code][2]

```
#setting size arrays
scatterSize = []
for eachGDP in gdp:
   size = abs(eachGDP)*300
   scatterSize.append(size)

ax.scatter(y_pos, gdp, color = 'purple', linewidth = .5, s = scatterSize, label = 'GDP')

plt.legend(loc = 'upper left',prop={'size': 10})
```

Comment: Solved: plt.legend(markersize = .2, loc = 'upper left',prop={'size': 10})

Answer (score 0):

Should have read documentation closer. There is an argument for markersize.

plt.legend(markersize = .2, loc = 'upper left',prop={'size': 10})

See fix:

[Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRLPh.png)